# Why after postback my summaryvalidator shows disabled requiredfield validator messages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, validationsummary

I'm using `javascript` to make dynamic `RequiredFieldValidators` with some functions which work perfect disabling and enabling them with this function:

```
function myValidatorEnabler(validator, enable) {
                validator.enabled = enable;
                ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);
        }
```

I'm also using a `asp:ValidationSummary` which works perfect before postback, but after the button is pressed all validators which were `disabled` are shown in the Summary. Is there any possibility to avoid this?

I tried using `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit()` at the end on my javascript function but it didn't work. Just in case, I'm using `UpdatePanel` and `ValidationGroup`

This is my asp:ValidationSummary:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="Error" DisplayMode="List"  EnableClientScript="true" ValidationGroup="DatAca" />
```

and this is my Button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEnd" runat="server"  Text="End" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="DatAca" />
```

Thanks in advance.